# Execute method with Action<T> argument using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How can i create a Action method to use as a argument to the following function?

```
public void When(Action<T> action) 
{
    if (internalValue != null)
        action(internalValue);
}
```

I have the MethodInfo on the method, and the parameter type like so:

```
var methods = value.GetType().GetMethods();
MethodInfo mInfo = methods.First(method => method.Name == "When");
Type parameterType = (mInfo.GetParameters()[0]).ParameterType;
```

But after that i have no idea how to make the actual Action method to pass as argument, i also do not know how to define the Action method body.

Comment: Well what do you want the action to do?

Comment: Something like:

Action<T> action = a => 
{ 
string internalValue = a.ToString().ToUpper(); 
...
...
}

Comment: "Something like" isn't very precise. What information do you have when you want to call this by reflection?

Comment: The When method belongs to a generic class called "public class ItemContainer<T> { }", that is a property in another class, the program is supposed to find all propertys that are of the type ItemContainer<T> and execute the When method with the Action argument, so T is not known, i can however get the type of T using
Type type = value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]

Answer (score 2):

```
mInfo.Invoke(value,
    delegate(<TheRuntimeTypeOf T> aTinstance)
    {
        // do something on a T
    });
```

But keep in mind that you're loosing the genericity.